# How does one use owners -> picture -> url images?

Tags: google-drive-api

I see these image links in the return output of drive listings for owner pictures. How does one use these images?

Specifically: a) What is the full path b) Is an access token and a certain minimum scope required to access the images ?

```
"owners": [
 {
  "kind": "drive#user",
  "displayName": "[DELETED]",
  "picture": {
   "url": "/c/u/[DELETED]/photos/private/AIbEiAIAAABDCK6F3MOr74uHQiILdmNhcmRfcGhvdG8qKDA1OTRiNmYyYmYzNWFmMTk1OTQyODllZDY0MWE5MTBkZDdiZTBjYTgwAdQeDClRWHKobzHkSZ7WSUDjSh3q"
  },
  "isAuthenticatedUser": false,
  "permissionId": "10165133368294800816"
 }
],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The photos are all public profile photos, and respect all profile privacy options, so no authorization is required, usually.

The full url is made by prepending `https://google.com`. I think it would be better if the actual URL was returned. Hopefully Google can get that fixed.

Comment: Okay, no worries. I think there is value in just having abbreviated URLs ( i.e. saves bytes on the wire for both Google and us ). Just having the documentation reflect what is needed for the full URL is sufficient, its an easy code change on our side to form the full URL.